# Simple control flow in scalaz effect

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

Take this simple bit of code:

```
var line = "";

do {
  println("Please enter a non-empty line: ")
  line = readLine()
} while (line.isEmpty())

println("You entered a non-empty line: " + line)
```

It's definitely not particularly elegant, especially with the unfortunate scoping of `line` -- however, I think it's quite simple to read.

Now trying to translate this directly to scalaz effect, I have come up with:

```
def nonEmptyLine: IO[String] = for {
   _ <- putStrLn("Please enter a non-empty line:")
   line <- readLn
   r <- if (line.isEmpty()) nonEmptyLine else IO(line)
}  yield r


(for {
  line <- nonEmptyLine
  _ <- putStrLn("You entered a non-empty line: " + line)
} yield ()).unsafePerformIO
```

Which makes me feel like I'm missing something, as this doesn't feel like an improvement at all? Is there some higher order control flow stuff I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this (at least arguably) a lot prettier by skipping the `for` notation and using the combinators  `*>` and `>>=` to pipe everything together:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._, IO._

val prompt = putStrLn("Please enter a non-empty line:")

def report(line: String) = putStrLn("You entered a non-empty line: " + line)

def nonEmptyLine: IO[String] = prompt *> readLn >>= (
  (line: String) => if (line.isEmpty) nonEmptyLine else line.point[IO]
)
```

And then:

```
scala> (nonEmptyLine >>= report).unsafePerformIO
Please enter a non-empty line:
You entered a non-empty line: This is a test.
```

In general, though, I'm not sure you should expect code written using `scalaz.effect` to be more concise or easier to read than a straightforward imperative solution.